# Solaris 10 with Gnome: How do I rotate my screen?

Tags: gnome, display, solaris, rotate

Anyone know how to rotate your screen from landscape to portrait in Solaris 10 with Gnome?

**Update**: Have looked in:

Launch -> Preferences -> System preferences (has nothing relevant)

Launch -> Preferences -> Desktop preferences

- The most promising thing here is *Display* but I am 90% sure that there is nothing in there.  Inside Display there is:

  - Background
  - Fonts
  - Menus and Tool bars
  - **Screen Resolution** (just has resolution and refresh rate)
  - Screen Saver
  - Theme
  - Window behavior
- There are a number of other menus but I have dug through most of them and not found anything useful

Comment: What graphiccard do you have?

Comment: @Bobby: Sorry new to unix, how would I find that out?

Comment: Weird..  I had one answer but it has disappeared...  It was not correct but.. is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Display UI is indeed the place to look but it hasn't yet that choice available with your Solaris release. On OpenSolaris there is a Rotation chooser with Normal and Right, Left and Inverted, when supported by the hardware.

The equivalent CLI commands are `xrandr -o right`, `xrandr -o normal`

The NVidia driver documentation states a GEForce 2 or better card is required. No idea about other vendors.

Comment: bash: xrandr: command not found.  Maybe it is not in my path.  Where should I look for it?  Thanks!

Comment: The command is there /usr/X11/bin/xrandr and part of the SUNWxorg-client-programs package.

Comment: Hey, I could not get that working, so I created a new thread:
http://superuser.com/questions/121489/rotate-screen-using-xrandr-on-solaris-10