# Rotate screen using xrandr on Solaris 10

Tags: unix, display, solaris, syntax, xrandr

How do I call the xrandr command?  I want to rotate my screen 90 deg. clockwise.  Here is the usage:

```
% xrandr -help
usage: xrandr [options]
  where options are:
  -display <display> or -d <display>
  -help
  -o <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
            or --orientation <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
  -q        or --query
  -s <size>/<width>x<height> or --size <size>/<width>x<height>
  -r <rate> or --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  -v        or --version
  -x        (reflect in x)
  -y        (reflect in y)
  --screen <screen>
  --verbose
  --dryrun
  --prop or --properties
  --fb <width>x<height>
  --fbmm <width>x<height>
  --dpi <dpi>/<output>
  --output <output>
      --auto
      --mode <mode>
      --preferred
      --pos <x>x<y>
      --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
      --reflect normal,x,y,xy
      --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
      --left-of <output>
      --right-of <output>
      --above <output>
      --below <output>
      --same-as <output>
      --set <property> <value>
      --off
      --crtc <crtc>
  --newmode <name> <clock MHz>
            <hdisp> <hsync-start> <hsync-end> <htotal>
            <vdisp> <vsync-start> <vsync-end> <vtotal>
            [+HSync] [-HSync] [+VSync] [-VSync]
  --rmmode <name>
  --addmode <output> <name>
  --delmode <output> <name>
```

This is what I tried:

```
% xrandr -o left
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  159 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  16
```

I am running Solaris 10.

Also tried a few variations of:

```
xrandr --output --rotate left
```

Although I am unsure of what the difference is between this and the orientation shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the way you tried but the error message means your X driver doesn't support rotating the screen or that it is disabled.

Try adding

```
Option         "RandRRotation" "True"
```

in the Screen section of your xorg.conf file.

Comment: Where can I find that file?  I looked in /usr/x11 (where the command is).  Any ideas?

Comment: If you haven't that file, create it. Modern Xorg do not need an xorg.conf file to run as defaults values are used.

The way to do it might depend on the driver used but you do not tell it.

Comment: Where should I create it?

Comment: Usually in /etc/X11/xorg.conf, although here are several other documented places where the Xorg server looks for its configuration file. The tool you use might already know it. Why don't you tell what driver you use ??

Comment: Or that the X server doesn't support it, as Solaris 10 includes both Xsun (no randr support) and Xorg (has randr support if the driver supports it), as well as other X servers being available including Xnewt (Sun Ray), Xvfb, Xvnc, and Xephyr - some with randr, some without.